# Turtle Beach XL1 & PC Connectivity

Tags: audio-hardware

I bought a Turtle Beach XL1 headset earlier today and i was going to connect them to my computer via the PC/PS3 adapter that you can by for it. After I bought them, I realized the one chart that I looked at has the wrong info. The PC/PS3 adapter is only compatible for certain headsets and mine is not one of them.

So my question is, the XL1s may not be compatible, but can they still be used with this adapter?

[Would this jack work to connect it to my computer for recording](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062475&clickid=prod_cs)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really on-topic here.  It's more a general hardware issue than a gaming one.

Comment: could someone please give me the link to buy an adapter for the XL1 to plug into PC or PS3 i would really appreciate it :)
i need this info as i bought it for 20 quid of a mate today, shall i get my money back?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about connecting headphones to PC, not anything to do with gaming.

Comment: Where does questions like these go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately not.  The PC/PS3 compatible ones usually work by transmitting audio data via the USB connection.  You'd likely be able to get it to work for hearing things, with the proper audio adapters, but not for working with the headset's mic.

Comment: That's crap! I want my money back now! The chart clearly said I could use the adapter for the headset, when I really couldn't... Urg

Comment: Return policies for hardware are generally pretty lenient compared to software - especially this time of year due to the abundance of gift giving.

Comment: I already opened the packaging (It was in a plastic case so i had to cut part of that off), and as much as I could , IN CASE something did happen. does that mean I could return it?

Comment: I edited the main post, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can connect them to your P.C. All you really need is a gold 3.5mm male to 2.5mm female audio stereo headset jack adapter and a PC to Stereo 3.5mm 2 RCA Female Cable. Both are very cheap.

Be sure to plug the angled gold male piece into the turtle Beach slot on the amplifier, then plug the original gold male piece into the 3.5mm male to 2.5mm female adapter, and plug that into the microphone jack on your computer and finally plug the gold male piece of the PC to Stereo converter into the headphone jack and that should do it.